# ksqlDB Java Client unable to surface connection exception

Tags: java, spring-webflux, ksqldb, vertex

I'm using

```
implementation ('io.confluent.ksql:ksqldb-api-client:7.3.1')
```

and I'm running into issues throwing exception on connection loss on the code below

```
@Override
public <T> Flux<T> select(Query query, Class<T> entityClass) throws DataAccessException {
    String tableName = Objects.requireNonNull(mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(entityClass)).getTableName().toString();
    logger.info("Executing ksqlDB push query: SELECT * FROM" + tableName + " EMIT CHANGES;");
    return Flux.create((FluxSink<io.confluent.ksql.api.client.Row> sink) ->
                    client.streamQuery("select * from " + tableName + " " + emitChangesString(entityClass) + ";")
                            .thenAccept(streamedQueryResult -> streamedQueryResult.subscribe(RowSubscriber.fromSink(sink)))
            )
            .flatMap(row -> {
                try {
                    return Flux.just(objectMapper.readValue(row.asObject().toJsonString(), entityClass));
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    logger.error("ksqlDB Exception occurred while object mapping record from table:" + e);
                    return Flux.empty();
                }
            })
            .doOnError(throwable -> logger.error("Exception occurred during ksqlDB push query processing"));
}
```

I would expect the .doOnError() to be hit when i disconnect my internet connection but instead nothing happens and no errors are thrown.

Am I missing something here to be able to determine when the connection is lost?

Comment: It seems like there is nothing baked into the ksqldb Java client to detect if there was a connection drop while a push query is running. The only error we’re able to surface is if there is a connection drop while there is consumption of records in progress, but if we enter an idle state and drop connection, there is zero indication that the connection has dropped from the client and you are not able to surface any kind of error.

Comment: check how errors are handled in `RowSubscriber` and make sure that `sink.error(e)` is called. also, some errors could occur outside of the subscriber. It could be that you need to add `.exceptionally` block and propagate exception there `sink.error(e)`

Comment: It was actually a vertx error did not trigger any of the RowSubscriber onError hooks. It was a null pointer exception that was uncaught and was unable to be caught since the code that triggers the NPE is library code that is only readable. Ended up using webclient straight for more flexibility and control.

Comment: interesting combination vertx & spring-webflux.

Comment: No vertx, just used Spring Webflux straight with the ksqldb rest api

Comment: hmm, "It was actually a vertx error". Anyway, I'm glad you found the root cause.

Comment: Yeah I meant that, we opted to not use the ksqldb Java client library since it was locked into using vertx where it was inflexible and we were triggering a null pointer exception that was unable to be caught, so instead we are using Webclient and the ksqlDB REST API sow we have more control over HTTP exception handling and configuration around TCP keep alive. Errors surface much more clearly as well.